# Error While Using Composer Install Command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, composer-php, laravel-5.4

I am trying to install a package form composer require but i getting the below error
[RuntimeException]
Could not delete /var/www/html/santrack/vendor/mtdowling/cron-expression/composer.json:

composer looks like

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "appstract/laravel-bootstrap-components": "^0.2.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "jenssegers/mongodb": "^3.3",
    "laracasts/flash": "^3.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.7"
},
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing the file on your own?

Comment: Your user account probably isn’t the one that originally setup the `vendor/mtdowling` directory, try to `chown` to your user account or switch to that user.